# Linq list of string match any inside string

Tags: linq

Ok, so given the array:

```
string[] keywordlist = new string[] { "match", "found" };
```

This returns the error "The data types text and text are incompatible in the equal to operator":

```
 List<StaticPage> matches = cdc.StaticPages.Where(x=>keywordlist.Contains(x.BodyCopy)).ToList();
```

And this does not give an error but returns 0 results although there are several rows that should meet the condition, and I don't see why I would need to send the table to a list (at least never had the need to do it before):

```
List<StaticPage> matches = cdc.StaticPages.ToList().Where(x=>keywordlist.Contains(x.BodyCopy)).ToList();
```

So whats wrong? I just want to return any rows in witch --> any <-- of the words in the array is found in the "BodyCopy" field.

Comment: cdc.StaticPages can you list values from here?

Comment: `Contains` looks for a substring, which is not what you are looking for. What you are up to is something like `keywordlist.Any(k => x.BodyCopy.Contains(k))`. And the first version is not working because db `text` type is very limited as to what you can do with it, so you query might not have direct translation to SQL

Comment: @Andrei that seems to do the trick ".Where(x => keywordlist.Any(k => x.BodyCopy.Contains(k))).ToList();" I have results coming back now! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line

```
List<StaticPage> matches = cdc.StaticPages.Where(x=>keywordlist.Contains(x.BodyCopy)).ToList();
```

means that you are looking such pages that have `BodyCopy` equals to one of keywords. Instead of that, you need the following line:

```
var matches = cdc.StaticPages.Where(
    x => keywordlist.Any(keyword => x.BodyCopy.Contains(keyword))
).ToList();
```

It means that your are looking such pages the have one of keyword inside their content.

A full snippet:

```
class StaticPage
{
    public string BodyCopy;
}
static void Main()
{
    string[] keywordlist = { "match", "found" };
    var cdc = new
    {
        StaticPages = new List<StaticPage>
            {
                new StaticPage {BodyCopy = "text match text"},
                new StaticPage {BodyCopy = "text text"},
                new StaticPage {BodyCopy = "text found text"}
            }
    };
    var matches = cdc.StaticPages.Where(
        x => keywordlist.Any(keyword => x.BodyCopy.Contains(keyword))
    ).ToList();
    foreach (var staticPage in matches)
        Console.WriteLine(staticPage.BodyCopy);
}
```

Output:

```
text match text
text found text
```